# Java threads synchronization - simple sequence of numbers

Tags: java, multithreading

i need to generate sequence of numbers (1 2 3 4 5 6...) using multiple threads in java. So far i have this:

All threads have reference to same instance of this class:

```
class Number{
    private static int number;

    public Number (int i){
        number = i;
    }

    public synchronized int getNext(){
            number+=1;
            return number;
    } 
}
```

And in each thread, i am looping this part of code:

```
System.out.print(number.getNext());
```

As a result, i am getting sequence of numbers, but they are not sorted and look like: 1 3 2 5 4 8 9 7 6 ....

How can i synchronize my threads and as a result, get sorted numbers? (1 2 3 4 5...)

Thanks for each advice.

Comment: What's the point of multithreading this sequential program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the printing to happen together with incrementing, you have to synchronize them both. The simplest fix in your case is:

```
synchronized(number) {
  System.out.print(number.getNext());
}
```